# I'm receiving an uncaught type error when clicking on a date on fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, salesforce-lightning, fullcalendar-4

Receiving below error when trying to click on a date on my fullcalendar. From what I've read, it seems the be an error when retrieving information from the core file.

I've had the base requirements, such as having selectable = true. When I don't have this line of code, no error appears

---NewAppointment.cmp

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!join(',', 
                       $Resource.Fullcalendar + '/packages/core/main.js',
                       $Resource.Fullcalendar + '/packages/daygrid/main.js',
                       $Resource.Fullcalendar + '/packages/moment/main.js',
                       $Resource.Fullcalendar + '/packages/interaction/main.js',
                       $Resource.Fullcalendar + '/packages/timegrid/main.js')}"
             styles="{!join(',', 
                      $Resource.Fullcalendar + '/packages/core/main.css',
                      $Resource.Fullcalendar + '/packages/daygrid/main.css',
                      $Resource.Fullcalendar + '/packages/timegrid/main.css')}"
             afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.renderCalendar}"
      />
```

---NewAppointmentController.js

```
 renderCalendar : function(component, event, helper) {

    var events = component.get('v.eventList');
    var currCalendar = component.find('calendar').getElement();
    var newCalendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(currCalendar,{
        plugins: ['dayGrid', 'moment', 'interaction', 'timeGrid'],
        eventSources: [component.get('v.eventList')],
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
        dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view, resource) {
            alert('clicked ' + date.format() + ' on resource ' + 
                  resource.id);
        },
        selectable: true,
        dateClick: function(info) {
            alert('clicked ' + info.dateStr);
        },
        select: function(info) {
           alert('selected ' + info.startStr + ' to ' + info.endStr);
        }
    });
    newCalendar.render();
}
```

Expected result would be that I receive an alert of the date that gets selected. Instead, I receive the below error

```
aura_prod.map.js:47164 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
throws at https://--/Fullcalendar/packages/core/main.js:126:30 TypeError: 
Illegal invocation

at elementClosest (main.js:126)
at SimpleDayGrid.DateComponent.isValidDateDownEl (main.js:4070)
at EmitterMixin.DateClicking._this.handlePointerDown (main.js:1128)
at applyAll (main.js:988)
at EmitterMixin.triggerWith (main.js:3523)
at EmitterMixin.trigger (main.js:3518)
at EmitterMixin.HitDragging.handlePointerDown (main.js:988)
at applyAll (main.js:988)
at EmitterMixin.triggerWith (main.js:3523)
at EmitterMixin.trigger (main.js:3518)
```

(EDIT)

I did some more testing, and found out I was wrong about not getting an error if I didn't have selectable=true. It might be an error on the instantiation of the calendar.

I've provided a small image below to how the calendar looks right now. The buttons at the top work perfectly fine and is able to change the date of the calendar. The error only shows up when I press any of the date boxes.
https://gyazo.com/4f7636b27a9c535f20f3fc8b1c5dbadd

I've also noticed I receive two errors, they just happened in succession and are essentially the same error, except one was for dateClicking and the other was dateSelecting

(EDIT)

I've narrowed down the issue. The top buttons work fine, and if I click outside of the calendar I don't receive the error. The error only occurs when I click on any of the dates on the calendar, which then also prevents me from right clicking on the screen. I've narrowed it down that after I removed the **interaction** plugin call from the JS file, I stopped receiving the error. The problem seems to revolve around this plugin.